# How can I make a div appear over specific area tags on an image on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have some javascript that moves an image continuously left.  When you mouseover the image, I want the scrolling to stop, and I want a slightly transparent div with some custom text to appear over whatever area tag your mouse is over.

Here is the JS I'm using, and I commented out where things should happen.  How would I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var date = new Date();
                var style = "day"
                if (date.getHours() >= 17 && date.getHours() <=5) {
                    style="night";
                }
                setInterval(wells_fancy_slider, 50);
                $('area').hover(function() {
                                    // here is where the code should go
                    paused = true;
                }, function() {
                                    // here is where you hide the div
                    paused = false;
                })
            })

            function wells_fancy_slider() {
                if (!paused) {
                    if (parseInt($('#pic1').css('left')) < -2770) {
                        $('#pic1').css('left', '5586');
                    }
                    if (parseInt($('#pic2').css('left')) < -2770) {
                        $('#pic2').css('left', '5586');
                    }
                    if (parseInt($('#pic3').css('left')) < -2770) {
                        $('#pic3').css('left', '5586');
                    }
                    $('#pic1, #pic2, #pic3').css('left', '-=5');
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you post a picture or something, displaying the desired effect? Seems you already figured "how", so its hard to write the code when we arent able to see the desired result.

Comment: Do you ever validate your JS?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it will fit your needs:

**CSS:**

`#mydiv{position:absolute;display:none}`

```
    $('area').hover(function() {                

   $('mydiv').offset({ top: $(this).offset().top, left: $(this).offset().left}).fadeIn();
                paused = true;
            }, function() {
                   $('#mydiv').hide();
                paused = false;
            })
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately :\ the top and left properties come up as "auto"

Answer (score 3):

Try this one..

```
t = setInterval(wells_fancy_slider, 50);

$('#area').hover(function(e) {
    clearInterval(t);
    var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); // or $(this).parent().offset();
    var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

    paused = true;
}, function() {
    clearInterval(t);
    t = setInterval(wells_fancy_slider, 50);
    paused = false;
});
```

Comment: This works, except the popup comes up where the mouse is, not where the area position is...